# Is it possible to log offset updates and commits in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

Is it possible to configure Kafka logging to show when the offset is updated and or committed?

I can get the offset value with `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`. But is there any way to have it in the logs when the commit of the offset happens and by which consumer?

How should I modify the log4j configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

From the brokers, I don't think there's anything to log for this information.

So, you would need to modify your code to add callbacks to each producer action to know when their send events got acked, and the returned metadata would include the partition and offset.

Then from consumers, you can disable auto commits and log after using `commitSync` to block and guarantee you're logging the correct information. Or you can pass a `OffsetCommitCallback` to `commitAsync` if you don't care about the order of the log file output